First stack exchange post, How to learn the latex 3 and lualatex languages (or together?)
my name is Lars. I am wanting to learn the latex 3 and lualatex standards (or preferably the combination) for the latex language. I have no experience with coding, programming. Or anything of the sort. I am wanting to learn mathematics and more importantly learn how to replace word for my work. I would love to know how exactly I could start fresh with the best standards in Latex today. Is here perhaps a textbook or guide on how to learn these? Or a tutorial on how to learn these standards? Please pardon me if I sounded incompetent. Please have a nice day.
The linked question is not referring to latex3 and lualatex. This is why mine is different. I was told t learn the latest standard by an advisor at school

All three of (1) typesetting a document with LaTeX, (2) programming with expl3 (aka LaTeX3), and (3) programming with Lua (via LuaTeX) are essentially completely unrelated. You probably want to start with (1); “Learn LaTeX” and the Overleaf Tutorial are both good places to start. For learning (2) or (3), there unfortunately aren't any great resources, but you'll want to start by learning typesetting first regardless.

@MaxChernoff this is referring to latex 2e, an old standard

LaTeX2e is the most recent version of LaTeX, at least as far as typesetting is concerned. I totally understand why you would think that LaTeX3 is the more recent version given how many older posts say that (I thought that too at first), but see A brief history p. 81 for an explanation of this.

LaTeX2e is the current standard and the l3 programming  layer is a part of it see e.g https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572177/2388

@Shlawg54 latex2e is the current latex. Most recent release was last month: LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2

To replace Word with very success  you do not need more than (1) a brief and basic tutorial of  LaTeX (the 2e), know the existence 1-2 dozens of common packages (that can use latex 3 or lua internally)  and (3) spend  time in CTAN to discover some more hidden gems (less popular packages). There are thousands of packages, so the only important to learn is that there are  package manuals. Programing with latex 3 or lua is only for the case that the whole CTAN is not enough to solve your very odd requirements, or you want to be a package developer/maintainer.
